# How to get around calling Wait inside of a task

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have code something like this:

```
var myTask = requiredTask.ContinueWith(_=>
{
    var otherTasks = from item in otherObjects select item.DoSomethingAsync();
    Task.WaitAll(otherTasks);
    // do my real work
});
```

My understanding is that the call to WaitAll is going to block and hold up a thread in the thread pool while the (IO bound) subtasks are completing.  My question is:

1. Is my assumption about tying up a thread pool thread correct?
2. If so what is the best method to avoid doing this?

Note that this is for a library that needs to support .NET4/Windows XP so using `await` is not an option.

Comment: If you include an [extra assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/), you can use `async`/`await` with .NET 4. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) and build with a compatible IDE (VS2012+), you can use `async`/`await` with .NET 4. Then you can [`await Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx), e.g.

```
var myTask = await requiredTask;
var otherTasks = from item in otherObjects select item.DoSomethingAsync();
await Task.WhenAll(otherTasks);
// do my real work
```

Since `Task.WhenAll` was added in .NET 4.5, not in the Microsoft.Bcl.Async assembly, this is how you'd do it in .NET 4:

```
var myTask = await requiredTask;
var otherTasks = (from item in otherObjects select item.DoSomethingAsync()).ToList();
foreach (var otherTask in otherTasks)
    await otherTask;
```

I also threw in a `ToList()` so that if you use `otherTasks` later (e.g. to get results), the expression will not be reevaluated.

Comment: There's no real need to use `await` here.  You just need `WhenAll` on it's own.

Comment: @Servy `WhenAll` returns a `Task` that indicates when all of the tasks passed in are complete, so you do need to `await` it. Maybe you're thinking of `WaitAll` (which was in the question), which doesn't return until all of the tasks passed in are complete.

Comment: All that he needs in the question is a task representing when all of the tasks are done that he can put in a variable (`myTask`).  What he does with that task we have no idea.  It may make sense to await it, it may just be returned from a method, it could be passed to another method, or who knows what.

Comment: The only problem with this is that `WhenAll` was introduces in 4.5 however the key part of the question is how to get avoid holding a thread while waiting for IO and `await` and a foreach loop does this nicely.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. For such a trivial example, the equivalent is a simple `foreach` loop. It is significant, though, to trigger all of the `Task`s before `await`ing any of them.

Comment: @TimS. Note that 4.0 has a `ContinueWhenAll` that you can use either directly, or just as a very straightforward and clearly valid implementation of your own `WhenAll` method.